# Всплывающее вертикальное подменю, нюансы

Tags: jquery, css, меню, popupmenu

Столкнулся с проблемой. Сделал вертикальное меню со всплывающим подменю при наведении. Но при движении мыши по диагонали вниз естественно всплывает следующее подменю. Необходимо, чтобы при движении мыши ровно по вертикали меню открывались, а по диагонали нет, что давало бы возможность пользователю навести мышкой на подменю.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: всё относящееся к вопросу должно быть в вопросе. Ссылки на какие-то сторонние сайты (кроме песочниц) расценивается как спам.... для демонстрации нужного эффекта, если угодно, можете записать видео с этим меню, переконвертировать его в gif анимацию и приложить это изображение

Comment: Для демонстрации эффекта человеку нужно зайти по ссылке и посмотреть. При чем тут спам. Сделайте ссылку неактивной, скрытой как угодно.

Comment: **всё относящееся к вопросу должно быть в вопросе**

Answer (score 2):

**1 Вариант**

Используйте невидимый элемент (это может быть дополнительный `div` или псевдо-элемент `:before` `:after`). Расположите его так, чтобы он перекрывал меню под нужным углом. (я выделил его голубым цветом, но на самом деле его не должно быть видно) (схема принципиальная, у вас может быть вертикальное, горизонтальное меню) [image: схема принципиальная, у вас может быть вертикальное, горизонтальное меню]
Даже если он будет невидим, он будет загораживать собой нижележащие элементы. Элемент можно повернуть с помощью CSS свойства `transform`

**2 Вариант**

Временная задержка. Вместо того чтобы сразу запускать открытие меню, сделайте небольшой таймаут:

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function() { /*Здесь код открытия меню*/ }, 500);
```

тогда при наведении на подменю вы сможете отменить запланированное действие

```
clearTimeout(timerId);
```